# Escalating the request to close any question when moderators don't

Tags: discussion, flags

It occurred to me so many times that even after flagging a question which is an exact duplicate or may be not a real question at all, moderators sometimes don't close the question.

What are my options in that situation? Can I escalate it?

Comment: Why do you see this as a problem? Why do you need _immediate_ action?

Comment: not immediate action, but i see two questions which are exact duplicate and moderators dont close them

Comment: You can try becoming moderator yourself, that's about the only option.

Comment: @PiyushSardana What questions are you referring to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193382/how-to-validate-the-rows-of-the-subgrid-of-jqgrid-in-jquery

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont know how that queue system works. If you can provide my any link about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You [provided a link in the comment of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193382/how-to-validate-the-rows-of-the-subgrid-of-jqgrid-in-jquery). It's not that moderators declined your flags, *we hadn't seen it yet*.  There are currently 202 open flags waiting for moderator review on the site.  About 20 minutes ago, there were over 300.  Yours was one of those 300.  It would have probably been resolved in a few hours.

You flagged the question two hours ago (although it says 9:33:10 Z), and wrote this post an hour ago (however, the timestamp is 10:28:01 Z).  We need a little more lead time than that.

Give us time to work for you. Flagging *does not* result in an instantaneous response from a moderator.  Sometimes it can be hours before we get to flags.  Our average handling time is a little over 5 hours for this month.  That's a good lead time.

In this particular case, we hadn't seen the flag yet, so it's not as if we declined to handle the post.

If and when you do see a declined flag when flagging a duplicate, then you know that the moderator who reviewed it decided to decline it.  Even when a moderator declines a flag, that doesn't stop the community from taking action.

I went ahead and resolved the flag. Keep on Keepin' on.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

If a moderator looks at it and decides that the two aren't exact duplicates, and the folks reviewing close votes don't think it is an exact duplicate - perhaps it isn't an exact duplicate after all?

Why the rush to close it off? It will eventually get closed or closed as a duplicate. If you really feel the need to intervene, why not just leave a comment saying that it is a duplicate and a link to the question that you think it is a duplicate of. (This will give high rep users a good incentive to look at your link - and if they agree with you, cast a close vote - Doing this *could* close the question much quicker than waiting for a moderator to get through their list and get to your flag).

Comment: well Fluffeh, I dont want to rush it off. But when i see stats, that in last 7 days 50 % questions were not answered, It annoys me, because out of those 50 % , 20 % should be closed.

Comment: @PiyushSardana And the queue on the close votes list is declining (at least on StackOverflow) and getting lower each day. It has gone down around 7k items in the last few weeks. Eventually it will get so short that it will be like the edits queue - pretty much instant.